# Weird behaviour with unordered_map of vectors and erase-remove idiom in C++14

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, c++14

So I'm computing `Biconnected Components (BCC)` in an `undirected graph`, after computation my algo includes some `Bridge` edges in some BCCs as well, so as a post-processing step I run a loop on each `BCC` (represented as a `vector<pair<int, int>>`, each `pair<int, int>` representing an `edge` in that BCC.) Here's how I did it:

```
auto pred = [&Bridges](pair<int, int>& edge) -> bool
{
    return Bridges.find(edge) != Bridges.end();
};

for (auto bcc = BCC.begin(); bcc != BCC.end(); bcc++)
{
    vector<pair<int, int>>& BCCList = (bcc->second);
    BCCList.erase(remove_if(
        BCCList.begin(), BCCList.end(), pred), BCCList.end());
}
```

`Bridges` is a `set` of `pair<int, int>`s again, containing all Bridge edges found by my algo.

`BCC` is a `unordered_map<int, vector<pair<int, int>>>`.

The above code works as intended, removes any Bridge edges that may have been in a BCC vector before. BUT, if I make a slight change and do this:

```
auto pred = [&Bridges](pair<int, int>& edge) -> bool
{
    return Bridges.find(edge) != Bridges.end();
};

for (auto bcc = BCC.begin(); bcc != BCC.end(); bcc++)
{
    vector<pair<int, int>> BCCList = (bcc->second);
    BCCList.erase(remove_if(
        BCCList.begin(), BCCList.end(), pred), BCCList.end());
}
```

All I did was remove the `&` before `BCCList` in the first line inside the `for-loop`. This makes the code not work, and it produces a result as if this `for-loop` never executed; no Bridge edges in any BCC are removed, thus computing wrong BCCs in the end. Please tell me why's this happening?

I always thought that if I have a `bcc` like iterator on an `unordered_map`, then `bcc->first` is the `key` (here, `bcc->first` should be an `int`) and `bcc->second` is the `value` (here, `bcc->second` should be `vector<pair<int, int>>`). Is this not correct? Why must I explicitly specify an `&` (a reference variable) for the code to work?

Does this behaviour have something to do with `remove_if` perhaps?

Comment: Removing the reference type will end up creating a copy of each item, trimming it down via your remove-if, then throwing all the work away. The original container remains unaffected.

Comment: Maybe useful: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#overview-refs https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
vector<pair<int, int>>& BCCList = (bcc->second);
```

Here, `BCCList` is a reference (an alternative name) for the vector stored in `bcc->second`. Whatever change you do to `BCCList` is actually done to `bcc->second`.

```
vector<pair<int, int>> BCCList = (bcc->second);
```

Here, `BCCList` is a **copy** of the vector stored in `bcc->second`. It's a separate object. Changes to it do not affect `bcc->second` at all.

Here is a simpler example, where it should be more obvious what's happening:

```
int data = 42;
int *bcc = &data;

int &ref = *bcc;
ref = 314;

int cop = *bcc;
cop = -42;
```

I don't think you'd expect the assignment `cop = -42;` to modify `data`. It's exactly the same situation in your code.

Answer (score 3):

In your original code, `BCCList` is a reference to an element in BCC. Everything you do on `BCCList`, you do it in reality to the original element.

When you remove `&` the `BCCList` is an independent value that is initialised with a copy of the original.  Everything you do to it is kept local to that value, and is lost at the next iteration (or when leaving the loop).